# IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection

Tags: java, spring, jndi

I got the following error when I have tried to hit DB for more than the number of max pool size.

```
  ERROR: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection.
```

Fetching data is working properly but when i try to save data through stored procedure, i'm facing issue.To invoke procedure we are using prepare statement. I closed the connections properly. I don't know whether the connection is returned to the pool or not?

Comment: When you say you are hitting the DB, are you doing it simultaneously meaning are the requests concurrent ?

Comment: Not simultaneously. Hitting one time. But when i try to do the same process then i'm getting error.